# Overide checkout process in Sylius

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, checkout, sylius

This is my first time working with sylius and i am having a hard time trying to get my hands on any form of information regarding it.

I would like to overide all of the checkout with my custom checkout.

I have tried to overide the routes but it doesnt seem to work.

i added this in my routes.yaml

```
sylius_checkout_address:
    path: /checkout/address
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: open_marketplace.controller.test_controller::helloWorld

sylius_checkout_select_shipping:
    path: /checkout/select-shipping
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: open_marketplace.controller.test_controller::helloWorld

sylius_checkout_select_payment:
    path: /checkout/select-payment
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: open_marketplace.controller.test_controller::helloWorld

sylius_checkout_complete:
    path: /checkout/complete
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: open_marketplace.controller.test_controller::helloWorld
```

i am just trying to see if i can even just echo hello world and die().

But i still get the old checkout process.

Comment: Did you run `php bin/console cache:clear` Also the doc https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.12/cookbook/shop/checkout.html#overwrite-routing-for-checkout recommend keeping the original sylius_checkout_select_shipping

Comment: Thank you :) I did do cache:clear, i know keeping the original route should be better but i don't understand anything ahaha Sylius is quite complicated for me right now so i just decided to overide everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwriting the routes in symfony is always possible.

The last route counts, so make sure you load the sylius routes first and then add your own route definition.

The route must be named exactly like the original one. I guess in your case the routes named:

```yaml
sylius_shop_checkout_start:
  # ...

sylius_shop_checkout_address:
  # ...

sylius_shop_checkout_select_shipping:
  # ...

sylius_shop_checkout_select_payment:
  # ...

sylius_shop_checkout_complete:
  # ...
```

Comment: Thank you i did this, but was still getting errors, i had to keep all the additionnal attributes (_sylius, event, repository, state_machine) in the .yaml file but only change the controller. I am quite new to symfony and Sylius.
Thanks a lot :)